# OnClick JS does NOT work with new elements in DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, dom

So here is a question.

I have HTML

```
<a class="callback">Callback</a>
```

I have external Jquery-file (with Bootstrap.js included)

```
$(".callback").on('click', function() {
var myModal = '<div><a id="callback"></div>';
$(myModal).modal('show');
});
$("#callback").on('click', function() {
//some actions
});
```

So ".callback"-event works fine because that link we have in the current DOM.
But "#callback"-event does NOT work. Maybe cos of that element appears after JS-file has loaded (seriously?).

Please, could anyone answer why "#callback"-event does NOT work?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use jQuery's event delegation syntax for on() when binding to dynamically created elements:

```
$(document).on('click', "#callback", function() {
```

Comment: what if I will use
$(".callback").click( function() {...
?

Comment: If you mean an class instead of an ID, the syntax is the same. `$(document).on('click', ".callback", function() {`. You need to bind to an element that exists when the page is loaded either way.

Comment: Sorry, I mean if I use right CLICK not ON.

Comment: You pass the event to on, whatever event you're using. You have to use on over click when binding to dynamic elements.